# Invoke ACPI/D-bus to run ruby script

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, dbus, acpi

I am creating a personal app to send a SMS to my phone if a background process detected the closing of my laptop lid.

I researched and there are several ways to do this:

1. ACPI - it listens for an event (laptop lid closing) and runs a bash script. However I'm not sure how to make it run a ruby script.
2. D-bus - allows communication between a desktop app and kernel, but I'll have to create a desktop app first, which is a bit of a overkill.

I am new to system programming, this project is just a way to test the waters of system programming. Hence my description above may not be accurate.

If you guys have any ideas how to achieve this app's functionality - sending a SMS to a specified phone number when the laptop lid is closed - I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a ruby script on an ACPI event.

First use `acpi_listen` to figure out what the event from a closing lid is.

In my case it looks like this:

`button/lid LID close`

Then you have to create an ACPI event handler (replace vim with your favourite text editor):
`sudo vim /etc/acpi/events/laptop_lid`

```
event=button/lid LID close
action=/etc/acpi/your_ruby_script.rb
```

Next, place your script in `/etc/acpi/` and make it executable:

```
sudo cp /path/to/your_ruby_script.rb /etc/acpi/your_ruby_script.rb
sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/your_ruby_script.rb
```

Finally just restart the ACPI daemon. This is dependant on the distro, but on upstart based distros it's `sudo service acpid restart` and on systemd based distros it's `sudo systemctl restart acpid.service`.